# Javascript compression via .htaccess?

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess

I'm using Apache.

I'm auto gzipping my HTML & CSS files on the fly using the following directive in my .htaccess file.

```
# Enable ETag
FileETag MTime Size


# Set expiration header
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
ExpiresByType text/css A2592000
ExpiresByType text/javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType text/js A2592000


# Compress some text file types
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/xml application/x-javascript text/javascript text/js


# Deactivate compression for buggy browsers
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
```

However, when I use the Firebug plugin for Firefox, I notice that my javascript files are NOT being gzipped (only my HTML and CSS files are).

**Any ideas why my JavaScript files are not being gzipped on the fly by Apache?**

Answer (score 11):

I figured it out, looks like I need it to be:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css text/xml application/x-javascript text/javascript application/javascript
```

To get javascript to compress/gzip

Comment: using this, I still have the same problem. Javascript and Css files are not compressed.

Answer (score 4):

Have you declared the text/javascript MIME type in Apache? If your server configuration points to, say, a `mime.types` file with one of these:

```
TypesConfig /private/etc/apache2/mime.types
```

then said file should include this line:

```
application/javascript              js
```

Otherwise, you should see one of these somewhere:

```
AddType application/javascript .js
```

At least, this is my first guess, if HTML and CSS files are being compressed and JavaScript files aren't.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting your declarations on separate lines. Here is the relevant portion of one of my .htaccess files which is functioning as desired. If you keep your scripts in a separate directory (such as /js) then this file should be in that directory as well.

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/js

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```